# Returning the range of a number as a palindrome

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, palindrome

I like to do programming challenges in my free time to teach myself and keep fresh, this one I can't seem to optimize though and it's driving me insane.

The goal is essentially, "Given a number, return the numbers leading up to it as a palindrome."

For example if you are given the input `5` the answer your program should return is: `123454321`

The catch? You have to solve it in as few characters as possible. The minimum needed seems to be 41 characters and I can't condense it past 76.

I have tried all sorts of solutions, here are a few:

```
# Note: "Palindromic_Number" is required. "def P(N):" will not work.
def Palindromic_Number(N):
    a = ''
    for x in range(1,N+1):
        a += str(x)
    return a + a[::-1][1:]


def Palindromic_Number(N):
    a = ''.join(map(str, range(1,N+1)))
    return a + a[::-1][1:]


def Palindromic_Number(N):
    a = ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1, N+1)])
    return a + a[::-1][1:]


# This one uses Python 2.7
Palindromic_Number = lambda N: ''.join(map(str, range(1,N+1) + range(1,N+1)[::-1][1:]))
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could shorten my code? I'm just looking for a point in the right direction where to look as this point.

Comment: `range(1,N)+range(N,0,-1)` should be shorter than using `a+a[::-1][1:]` afterwards as it allows you to not define `a` at all.

Comment: Forget it, it won't be so usefull. You can't add ranges in python 3. Only in python 2 where the builtin returns a list.

Comment: What's the input range? 1 to 9? 0 to 9?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try:

```
def Palindromic_Number(N):
    return int('1'*N)**2
```

just preforms `11111 * 11111` which equals `123454321`

47 chars.

---

Or, as a lambda:

```
Palindromic_Number=lambda N:int('1'*N)**2
```

41 chars.

Comment: 41 as a `lambda`, the apparent minimum, so I dare say you've nailed it :) (assuming input from 1-9)

Comment: @Sp3000 thank you! added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the last solution (that takes advantage of Python 2 style ranges) you could reduce this

```
range(1,N+1) + range(1,N+1)[::-1][1:]
```

in a couple of ways:

1. Instead of slicing the second range, create the reversed range directly as `range(N-1,0,-1)`
2. Making `N` come out of the second range allows changing `N+1` and `N-1` to `N` and `N`:

   ```
   range(1,N) + range(N,0,-1)
   ```

Comment: Slicing with `[-2::-1]` is shorter than `[::-1][1:]` by two bytes/chars. You can also remove the spaces on either side of the plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
Palindromic_Number=lambda n:(10**n/9)**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@x@QmJOZl1KUn5uZHO9XmpuUWmSbk5iblJKokGelYWigpZWnb6mppWX0v6AoM69EA1O5hpmm5n8A) (Includes test code to actually run the program.)

I know that you claimed that 41 is the minimum, but it's actually possible to do it in 40.

This uses the same strategy seen in the other answers, of squaring a repunit (a number made out of repetitions of the digit `1`). However, instead of using string operations to produce the repunit (and thus having to pay for `int` to convert string to integer), it generates the palindrome entirely arithmetically.

The basic idea here is that 10<sup>*n*</sup> is a `1` followed by *n* `0`s; if we subtract 1 we therefore get *n* `9`s, and dividing by 9 gives us *n* `1`s. Because Python 2 rounds integer arithmetic downwards, we can omit the subtraction of 1 (as it'll leave the answer higher by ⅑ than it should, which is a fraction that will disappear in the rounding), and we'll still get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

<del>`range` is a rather long name; with `lambda N,r=range:`/`def ...(N,r=range):` you can shave off a few characters if you</del> also remove all unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: Since this question migrated from Code Review I'm not sure whether it'll ping, but in any case aliasing `range` (5 chars) doesn't save any bytes when it's only used twice (compare `range;range` vs `r=range;r;r`)

Comment: It pings. I can't delete the answer, but I'm removing that part at least.